# How to deal with unicode within a form?

Tags: forms, user-behavior

I never thought about it before, but by having to validate a user's description (on both sides), I've faced a problem.

My users can write a short description about them, really short. In fact, the description can't be longer than 130 characters. They can write anything, there is no regex or something else.

It is more likely they'll add emoji rather than Chinese or Korean. But how should I approach this scenario, when I say to my user he can't write more than 130 characters but he get an error after 75 emojis or less? This isn't the behavior he expected. Isn't it a really bad user experience ?

Are there any solutions?
I'm also afraid about characters like Z͑ͫ̓ͪ̂ͫ̽͏̴̙̤̞͉͚̯̞̠͍A̴̵̜̰͔ͫ͗͢L̠ͨͧͩ͘G̴̻͈͍͔̹̑͗̎̅͛́  that I don't want.

Comment: Hi Thomas, this is more of an implementation problem. Check out this question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369513/how-to-count-the-correct-length-of-a-string-with-emojis-in-javascript/54369605

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need a UX solution rather than a technical one, if the character count can't be accurate then don't use one. Try an alternative pattern, such as a completion 'progress bar' that fills up as the user types.

Once they get over the maximum limit then let them know so they can amend it.

[image]